# mySQL fetch items order by row_number including a where an join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, window-functions

i have 2 tables: **usuario** (users) (id,email,active,id_rol) and **usuario_puntos** (users_points)(id,id_usuario,points)
I need to retrieve the list of users where the users has rol=3 and active =1 order by their points.

This is my query to retrieve ALL THE USERS, order by the position

```
SELECT @row_number:=CASE 
        WHEN 
            @puntos <> puntos THEN @row_number + 1 
        ELSE 
            @row_number END AS posicion, 
        @puntos:=puntos puntos,
        id_usuario,
        email,
        id_rol
        FROM usuario_puntos as up 
        inner join usuario as u on up.id_usuario=u.id
        ,
    (SELECT @puntos:=0,@row_number:=0) AS t 
    ORDER BY puntos DESC
```

And this is the response

[image: response fot the first query]

When i add **where u.id_rol=3 and active=1**
and the query looks like:

```
SELECT @row_number:=CASE 
        WHEN 
            @puntos <> puntos THEN @row_number + 1 
        ELSE 
            @row_number END AS posicion, 
        @puntos:=puntos puntos,
        id_usuario,
        email,
        id_rol
        FROM usuario_puntos as up 
        inner join usuario as u on up.id_usuario=u.id
        ,
    (SELECT @puntos:=0,@row_number:=0) AS t 
    where u.id_rol=3 and active=1
    ORDER BY puntos DESC
```

The response has incorrect positions

[image]

And i have no idea where to add that where to make this works!
Any idea? Thanks!

**UPDATES**
How is the tables currently
Usuario:

```
ID    Email         Active       id_rol
1     asd@asd.com   true         3
2     qwe@asd.com   false        3
3     zxc@asd.com   true         3
4     asd@asd.com   true         2
```

Usuario_puntos:

```
id    id_usuario    puntos    Some Other Stuffs...
1     1             100       xxxx
2     2             50        yyyy
4     3             200       zzzz
```

Comment: can you provide soemexample data to your results. Basically, the data gas to be sorted before hand, bus as i can't see where you get you results from it is not possible to make asuggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is much simpler done with window functions. `dense_rank()` would do what you want:

```
select 
    dense_rank() over(order by up.puntos desc) posicion,
    up.id_usuario, 
    u.email, 
    u.id_rol
from usuario u
inner join usuario_puntos up on up.id_usuario = u.id
where  u.id_rol = 3 and u.active=1
```

Your query makes it look like each user has a single row in `usuario_puntos`, but that assumption may be wrong. If so, you might need an aggregation query:

```
    select 
    dense_rank() over(order by up.puntos desc) posicion,
    up.id_usuario, 
    u.email, 
    u.id_rol
from usuario u
inner join (
    select id_usuario, sum(puntos) puntos
    from usuario_puntos 
    group by id_usuario
) up on up.id_usuario = u.id
where  u.id_rol = 3 and u.active=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am using MySQL for windows. So it's MySQL 5.7 this one.